# php web-service download problem

Tags: php, web-services

I am calling a web-service in PHP. When I call it from safari it shows the result properly in browser but when I call it in google chrome browser it downloads the php file instead of showing the result in browser.

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue.

Some projects are working fine some are having this issue.

I am using:
PHP Version 5.2.11
MAMP Pro

Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: could your provide some more details about the webservice?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to `.htaccess`

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

it sounds like the webserver isn't parsing the php properly

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I add this line? In 'httpd.conf' file I checked, I have this line: "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml" is this related to your answer?

Comment: that should be all you need. Have you restarted apache?
I've had this issue a few times and this has fixed it for me

Comment: I actually have restarted the mac too but not helpful. I didn't added anything in any file. The link I am referring to "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml" was already added in 'httpd.conf' file.